# JavaScript jQuery inside PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is a theoretical question.
My question is whether a jQuery function or script can be written inside a PHP function.
E.g.

```
<?php function phpfunc(){
$a=10; ?>

<script>var a ='<?php $a ?>'</SCRIPT> <?php } ?>
```

Is this possible and legal?

Comment: yes, that will work fine. Just echo `$a` instead of doing nothing with it.

Comment: This will work .and possible

Comment: @user3187838 the answer your selected doesn't answer your question, Edit your question or review the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's okay to do that. No, it's probably not a good idea. But there's nothing really stopping you.

Just be aware that if your variable happens to have a `'` in it, you'll get messed up.

So, whenever you want to pass a variable from PHP to JavaScript, be sure to use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(<?php echo json_encode($something); ?>);
</script>
```

Note that there's no quotes in the JavaScript part - `json_encode` will add quotes if needed. This can be used to pass almost any kind of variable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It is possible and Legal one too. we generally use the same when we require any server side value to be set on client-side on runtime.

Hope this answers your query.

Thanks Much!

Answer (score 4):

When php code is interpreted by the sever writing something like:

```
<?php 

function foo()
    {

        <script type=text/javascript> ... </script>

    }

?>
```

As part of the code in `<?php ?>` is interpreted as php and string inside the function doesnt represent any of php functions

You can echo javascript code (or any content of a HTML document) through your php code like:

```
<?php 

function foo(){

echo "<script type=text/javascript> alert('it works!)'; </script>";


} ?>
```

so when you execute the function, you wil add the javascript to the document by echoing it and therefore execute it.

You can also use php variables to echo variables to javascript like:

```
<?php 

function foo(){

echo "<script type=text/javascript> alert('{$phpVariable}'); </script>";


} ?>
```

or

```
<?php 

function foo(){

echo "<script type=text/javascript> var variableFromPHP = {$phpVariable}; </script>";


} ?>
```

Comment: I like the way he's doing it better than this. Why echo when you can just print the markup like in the original question?

Comment: the OP isn't clear where the code is written, I assumed the code is written on the server aswell.

the OP assumed client side code.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no(edit : yes).

javascript is executed on the client and only on the client.

You can however echo javascript to the client.

So something like this :

```
$JSfunction = "<script>alert('This is working')</script>";
```

can be echoed to the page by doing `echo $JSfunction;`

edit :

Since you didn't mention where that function is located, I assumed you meant the PHP function on the server side.

To be clear, If it's written on the html page itself, it's perfectly fine and can be done.

**complete answer**

```
<? function phpfunc(){
$a=10; ?>
<script>var a ='<?php echo $a ?>'</SCRIPT> <?php } ?>

<?php phpfunc() ?>
<script>console.log(a);</script>
```

You must echo that $a

Comment: This short answer is actually yes. His question is, `can jquery function or script be written inside php function`, and  it sure can.

Comment: @ohgodwhy Edited my answer, I assumed the question was asked on the serverside code.

Comment: Its used as client side.
If i do return `$a` . how will i return jquery script to html page ?

Comment: It's possible to write php code on html files. That's how:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may use it like in normal html page. Use script include inside echo inside the php script.

You may use it outside the php script normally. Use container tag for the same in the php page.

I hope it would help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question already has a lot of answers (one of which is accepted), and thus most likely doesn't need a new one unless the new answer provides some new information.